# (p4 api .NET) Setting multiple ClientOption members

Tags: c#, perforce

Currently when viewing my client settings, the Options field is "noallwrite noclobber nocompress unlocked nomodtime normdir."  I would like to check the compress and rmdir fields using the p4 api.  There is code to do each individually:

```
client.Options = ClientOption.Compress;
client.Options = ClientOption.RmDir;
```

However, after looking at the api and online, I cannot find a way to do both at the same time.  I can easily go into P4V and check both of these boxes, but I am trying to do it using the p4 api to make setup easier for future workspaces/clients.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you "or" the options together in your program?

Comment: No I don't believe so.

Answer (score 0):

Since the options in p4 options are flags

```
  [Flags]
  public enum ClientOption
  {
    None = 0,
    AllWrite = 1,
    Clobber = 2,
    Compress = 4,
    Locked = 8,
    ModTime = 16,
    RmDir = 32,
  }
```

You can pile them them up to get the expected result like this

```
P4.Client client = this.Repository.GetClient(clientname, null);
string  options= "noallwrite clobber nocompress unlocked nomodtime rmdir";

client.Options = new P4.ClientOption();

 if (!options.Contains("noallwrite"))
 {
     client.Options |= P4.ClientOption.AllWrite;
 }

 if (!options.Contains("noclobber"))
 {
    client.Options |= P4.ClientOption.Clobber;
 }
.....
```

Hope this helps!.